# PostGraphile "invalid algorithm" error with RS256 encrypted JWT toaken

Tags: jwt

I'm using JWT verification with PostGraphile 4.6.0 in a node project. Here is the the code snippet:

```
createServer(
postgraphile(env.DATABASE_URL, "public", {
  jwtVerifyAlgorithms: ["RS256"],
  jwtSecret: "./publickey.pem",
  jwtPgTypeIdentifier: "public.jwt_token",
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  graphiql: true,
  enhanceGraphiql: true,
  graphqlRoute: env.POSTGRAPHILE_ROUTE + "/graphql",
  graphiqlRoute: env.POSTGRAPHILE_ROUTE + "/graphiql",
})).listen(port, () => {
console.log("Listening at port:" + port);});
```

But when I use Postman to send RS256 encrypted JWT token, get error:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "invalid algorithm"
    }
]
```

}

And I created a function in Postgres to return JWT token, it always return HS256 encrypted JWT token. And I I use PostGraphile returned HS256 encrypted JWT token in Postman, JWT token is validated and the GrqphQL query returns fine.

Appears that the option "jwtVerifyAlgorithms" doesn't take effect.

Is there a way to make this work for RS256 encrypted JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

The [Postgraphile documentation](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-library/) states `jwtPublicKey` as the correct setting for providing the keys. Right now you are using `jwtSecret` with the string `"./publickey.pem"` which will *not* load the file, but instead use the file path as a password.
Make sure to load the file yourself using something like this:

```
...
jwtPublicKey: fs.readFileSync("./publickey.pem", "ascii")
...
```

#### Alternative via pgSettings

Worst case scenario you can also provide a custom `pgSettings` function that uses the `jsonwebtoken` npm library and verify the token yourself and write it to your settings.

Comment: One is expected to pass in the **secret** key into `jwtPublicKey`?

Comment: I edited the answer, this was unintentionally copy-pasted from the question

Answer (score 0):

## Set the sign algorithm in `jwtSignOptions`

The following configuration should work:

```
{
    ...
    jwtPublicKey: fs.readFileSync(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'ascii'),
    jwtSecret: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SECRET_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'ascii'),
    jwtSignOptions: { algorithm: 'RS256' },
    jwtTokenIdentifier: 'foo.bar',
    jwtVerifyAlgorithms: ['RS256'],
    ...
}
```

Comment: as long as Graphile does not create any JWTs but only parses them, you only need the publicKey. I think jwtSecret is not used if you supply the public key

Comment: true, just added this for other users coming across this post and wanting to sign too :)